# Alias table doesn't exist in where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

The question is from https://code.dennyzhang.com/sales-analysis-i

My solution is:

```
select seller_id
from (select seller_id, sum(price) price
        from Sales
        group by seller_id) S
# where S.price = max(S.price)
where S.price = (select max(price) from S)
```

However, the console gives me the error message:

```
Table 'test.s' doesn't exist
```

I replaced the last line of code by

```
where S.price = 0
```

This doesn't give me any error messages meaning that `S` table does exist. So my question is how does this error message come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`S` is a reference to a table that can be used to qualify columns.  It cannot be used in a `FROM` clause.

You can do what you want using a CTE:

```
with S as (
      select seller_id, sum(price) as price
      from Sales
      group by seller_id
     ) 
select seller_id
from S
where S.price = (select max(price) from S)
```